# How to implement "For Each PivotItem on PivotTable" in my code VBA Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have an issue with implementation function For Each PivotItem In PivotField. But it not works for me with error error 404 object required. I have a field in my pivottable and I want make visible all items that starts with "XYZ"

I`ve tried this but error appears

```
PivotTable.PivotFields("Voucher").CurrentPage = _
        "(All)"
    For Each PivotItem In PivotField.PivotItems
        If Left(UCase(PivotItem), 3) = "XYZ" Then
            PivotItem.Visible = False
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: What are `Pivottable` and `PivotField`? Are those variables that you set somewhere? Do you use `Option Explicit`?

Comment: No(
I dont work well with VBA(
Now, its works
Thank you
Appreciate it